# Show message row cannot be deleted in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I have a table view which has implementation to show delete button when user swipes on the row.

Everything works fine, but because of few conditions few rows cannot be removed.
How can i show a message on the UI, telling that row cannot be deleted.
I have following delegates implemented

```
tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:
```

Which returns true and false if row needs to be deleted or not.

But this methods get called when user lands on the screen or reload table view is called, so i cant put code in this delegate without putting some weird if conditions.

I got this working in the delegate

```
tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:
```

Which gets called only when user swipes.
But problem with this delegate is that in iOS 10.2 this delegate is being called for each row before, `canEditRowAtIndexPath` is called, so it works. But in latest iOS 11.2.2 `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` gets called after `canEditRowAtIndexPath`, which results in calling for only those rows which can be deleted and not for others. 
This pattern in iOS 11.2 does make sense but it doesn't allow me to use this delegate in my solution. Can anyone suggest how can i achieve the required behaviour?

Comment: Are you looking for `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`? With this you can show an alert based on condition by checking `editingStyle`

Comment: 'tableView:commitEditingStyle' , gets called only for those rows which have editing as enabled. So it can be used to confirm if user wants to delete row or not, but in my case i don't want to show user that this row can be deleted and just give a something like toast message, that row cannot be deleted.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to add a gesture recogniser to your cell.

Comment: @Skywalker i tried to put gestures on cells which i don't want to show as able to be deleted, but i cannot decide on my condition while i am creating a cell, i have to check each time when user swipes on row, to decide wether user can be shown an option to delete or not.

Comment: I think you should go with `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` and use the weird `if` conditions.

Comment: Its gonna get very unmanageable and complicated, because what i would be doing is trying to differentiate when is this delegate getting called from finger swipe or when is this delegate called from tableView.Reloaddata() or viewDidLoad().

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   // Set Condition which row delete 
   NSString *isDeleteorNot = [[arrInstaAccountList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Status"];

   // Set your if condition
   if ([isDeleteorNot isEqualToString:@"delete"])
   { 
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       return false;
   } 
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


   // Set Condition which row delete 
   NSString *isDeleteorNot = [[arrInstaAccountList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Status"];

   // Set your if condition
   if ([isDeleteorNot isEqualToString:@"delete"])
   { 
       cell.Toast.text = @"Delete";
   }
   else
   {
       cell.Toast.text = @"Not Delete";

   } 

}
```

Comment: I need to show something like toast message which tells user that user cannot swipe to delete on this row.

Comment: @soansaini this condition set tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

Comment: Not able to understand the code, cellForRowAtIndexPath will be called each time view is reloaded. I need to get information like when user swipes on top of Cell. and table has to decide whether row can be edited or not. At that moment i can show a toast message like cannot delete row and if its otherwise table can proceed ahead to show delete button on cell.

Comment: @soansaini I already added code to this `canEditRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: I am writing code in MVVM pattern, So my condition whether to allow is in VM, Which keeps on changing. I understand your code, but it doesn't solve my problem. I load my cell and when user swipes on a row i check for the condition and return yes and no, I can show a toast message over there but the problem is this method gets called all the time from different places like, when you reload the table this method get evaluated. So if i put toast message in this method, toast message gets displayed to many times. and mostly when user has just landed on the screen. So i cannot put code over here.